# Dynamics CRM restrict access by Owner Team

Tags: dynamics-crm, security-roles

I inherited a CRM implementation where about 90% of the CRM work has already been completed before the original developer left the project.  I am trying to fix access issues in regards to related entities.  The CRM Organization has a single Business Unit.

Whenever a Case (aka incident) is created, a plugin creates a new Owner Team. The Plugin adds the current user as the admin for the team and assigns the Case to the newly created team.  The team will have a name of "CT_XXX" where XXX represents the Case Title.  I haven't worked with CRM 2016 Online before and am not very familiar with the Owner Team.

How would I restrict access to custom entities to members of the CRM Team based on their relationship to the Case?  For example, when I open a Case (abc123), there are 10 related entities.  One of the entities, Private Documents, should only be accessible to members of the Owner Team (CT_abc123).  The other entities have no such restriction and are open to all users.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new team for every new case is not a solution I would recommend.

However, your plugin needs to assign a security role to the new team providing the required access rights. Users becoming a member of the team inherit the team's roles automatically.

Comment: From the research I did when I started, I thought the same thing about using the teams.  Unfortunately, as I mentioned, I inherited the project when it was mostly complete.  Plus, the Team set up is way more complex than just being the owner in this case but I digress.

I checked the plugin code and it is giving a permission the "Default_CRM_Team_Role" which as far as I can tell, isn't actually a role defined for the organization.  

Here is my take on what I need to do now:
1.  Create the team role

Comment: Here is my take on what I need to do now:
1.  Create the team role
2.  Remove the permissions on the restricted Entity for every role other than the team role.
3.  Set the team role permissions for that entity for User

Does that sound like it would solve the permissions problem?

Comment: @PaulHaan: design a security role with the permissions you need and let your plugin associate the role to the new team. A basic example can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334359.aspx